# Dispose delphi DLL changes from c# TransactionScope

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dispose, transactionscope

I have a Delphi DLL which opens a connection to a Database, makes some changes and commits the changes if all is OK.

```
DelphiDLLMethod("testingParameter");
```

I want to call the DLL from a c# project. In this project, I want to make some changes to the same Database but, if something fails, I want to Rollback all the changes, the changes from my code and the changes of the Delphi DLL.

```
using (TransactionScope txn = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        result = DLLMethod("testingParameter");
        MakeSomeDatabaseChangesFromThisProject();

        txn.Complete();
    }
    catch
    {
        txn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm testing with a TransactionScope and Dispose method, I want to prove that, if something goes wrong in my code, the changes dispose. But the changes from the DLL are always commited.

Comment: Your library needs to support transactions. It doesn't. You can't graft it on from the outside. Sounds like you should port all the code to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the Delphi library explicitly provides a mechanism for dealing with the transaction it creates (if any) you can't, as it will be isolated from the external (C#) side.